# SQL Sum after count

Tags: sql, sqlplus

```
Create Table DBONE AS (
Select distinct count(X) as Count, Y, Z
FROM Schema.Table
Where (Schema.Table.X like '%Retire%' or Schema.Table.X like '%Obsolete%')
Group by (X, Y, Z) 
)
ORDER BY X, Y, Z asc;
```

How can I abbend a sum to the end of the count(X) statement as either another column which calculates the sum of the count, or on the bottom of the row?

I've tried

```
Union All
Select 'SUM' X (table)
From Table
```

but this is incorrect

Comment: What SQL implementation are you using?

Comment: Didn't even know how to accept until you mentioned it, fixed, thanks.

Comment: SQL Plus communicating with a 10g rack

Comment: Do you want the sum of X or the sum of the count?

Comment: sum(x) doesn't make sense when x is a string and you're limiting its value with like

Comment: I'm not summing at all at the moment, I'm trying to figure out how it would fit in to my script thus far

Comment: Sum of the count is the same as count(*).

Comment: @user1821973 . . . You should provide sample data and an example of the results you want.  Your description does not seem clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query doesn't make real sense.  The count is always going to return "1", because you are grouping by X.  Also, you don't need the distinct when using group by.

You may want:

```
Select Y, Z, count(*) as count,
       sum(count(*)) over () as TotalCount
FROM Schema.Table
Where (Schema.Table.X like '%Retire%' or Schema.Table.X like '%Obsolete%')
Group by Y, Z
```

Comment: No, it works well at the moment, I just want to sum the one column X, it returns the actual count.